# A shorter solution to StreamReader in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have this basic code to read a file with `StreamReader` with Dotnet Core in VS Code. I can do similar operation in Visual Studios with .net `new StreamReader("file.json")` which looks small and compact.

I am looking for another class in dotnet core which could achieve similar results with less code

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("project.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)); 
            string line = " "; 

            while(line != null)
            {
                line = myReader.ReadLine(); 
                if(line != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line); 
                }
            }

            myReader.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, one of the reasons .NET core is **core** is that it is smaller, implementing only a subset of the full .NET framework. I don't know this particular case but I wouldn't be surprised if they just decided to reduce the number of overloads to the constructor.

Comment: Besides, what would a constructor specifying a file name mean on a system that doesn't have a file system in the normal sense? I wouldn't be surprised if `StreamReader` is available on all platforms and `FileStream` only available on platforms with a file system and the notion of "files".

Comment: @stakx another class that could achieve same result with less code which couldn't find in docs

Comment: In the full framework, the close method is redundant with Dipose. The recommended way to close a stream is to call Dispose through using statement in order to ensure closing stream even if an error happen. You can use `System.IO.File.OpenText()` to directly create a StreamReader.

Comment: @Kalten System.IO.File can't be found by IntelliSense. Its not present I guess also can't find version so I can add that to dependency file or install it with Nuget

Comment: You need [System.IO.FileSystem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem) package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the full framework, the close method is redundant with Dispose. 
The recommended way to close a stream is to call Dispose through using statement in order to ensure closing stream even if an error happen.

You can use System.IO.File.OpenText() to directly create a StreamReader.

Here, just what you need to to open and close a StreamReader :

```
using (var myReader = File.OpenText("project.json"))
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

The File class is in the [System.IO.FileSystem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem) nuget package

Answer (score 3):

Similar results with less code? Remove your unnecessary code... Will this not work???

```
try {
  using (StreamReader myReader = File.OpenText("project.json")) {
    string line = "";
    while ((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
      Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
  MessageBox.Show("FileRead Error: " + e.Message);
}
```